# I want items from second list which contains all items from first list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here is how my code looks like

```
List<Entity> lists = CacheManager.GetAllEntity();
List<long> firstLists = lists .Select <Entity,long>(x=>x.ID).ToList<long>();
List<Entity2> secondLists = CacheManager.GetAllEntity2();
```

where Entity2 looks like:

```
public class Entity2
{
    public long ID;     
    public long EntitytID;
}
```

Now suppose firstsLists contains `{1,2,3,4}`.
Second one contains

```
ID   EntitytID
1    1 
1    2
1    3
1    4
2    1
2    4
3    1
4    2
5    4
```

then my output should give me

```
ID   EntitytID
1    1 
1    2
1    3
1    4
```

since item id 1 has all values `{1,2,3,4}`.

Comment: and what if one of 1 has not one of (1,2,3,4), say 4th. What should be an expected output?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var results = secondLists
    .GroupBy(z => z.ID)
    .Where(z => firstLists.All(z2 => z.Select(z3 => z3.EntitytID).Contains(z2)))
    .SelectMany(z => z);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemsGroupedById = SecondList.GroupBy(item => item.id, item => item).ToList();
var listToReturn = new List<Entity2>();
foreach(var group in itemsGroupedById)
{
    var id = group.Key;
    var entityIdsInThisGroup = group.Select(items => items.EntityId).ToList();
    var intersection = entityIdsInThisGroup.Intersect(FirstList).ToList();
    if(intersection.Count == FirstList.Count)
    {
        listToReturn.Add(group);
    }
}
return listToReturn;
```

This will do the following -

1. Group all the items in your second list by their IDs.
2. In each group, it will intersect a list of the entity IDs in that group, and the ones in your first group.
3. If the intersection has all the elements of your first list, it will add the group to a list which you would return.